# Menu item disappears when it has a child

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use Bootstrap menu on my WordPress theme. I have created something that works partially with wp-bootstrap-navwalker. I am able to add items to my menu from WordPress and that works fine... But when I want to create sub-item or child to menu it disappears.

for example:
-Menu1
--Menu1-1
--Menu1-2
-Menu2
-Menu3
-Menu4

In this case I see only Menu 2,3,4. Menu 1 and sub-items are gone!

Here is how my code looks:
**Header.php**

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                        <!-- Stat Search -->
                        <div class="search-side">
                            <a href="#" class="show-search"><i class="icon-search-1"></i></a>
                            <div class="search-form">
                                <form autocomplete="off" role="search" method="get" class="searchform" action="#">
                                    <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" placeholder="Search...">
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <?php
                        }
                        ?>
                        <!-- End Search -->
                        <!-- Start Navigation List -->

                        <?php
                        wp_nav_menu( array(
                            'menu'              => 'primary',
                            'theme_location'    => 'primary',
                            'depth'             => 2,
                            'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
                            'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
                            'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
                        );
                        ?>
                        <!-- End Navigation List -->
                    </div>
```

**function.php**

```
function register_barlet_menu()
{
    register_nav_menus(array( 
        'primary' => __('Primary Menu', 'myTheme'), 
        'sidebar-menu' => __('Sidebar Menu', 'myTheme'), 
        'bottom-menu' => __('Bottom Menu', 'myTheme')
    ));
}
```

and this is my html file where it works good.

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <div class="search-side">
        <a href="#" class="show-search"><i class="icon-search-1"></i></a>
        <div class="search-form">
            <form autocomplete="off" role="search" method="get" class="searchform" action="#">
                <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" placeholder="Search...">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a class="active" href="“">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a>
            <ul class="dropdown">
                <li><a href="#">Service 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Service 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Products</a>
            <ul class="dropdown">
                <li><a href="#">Product 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Product 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Can anyone help me to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I believe changing the `depth`-value in your `wp_nav_menu()`-array will fix your problem. Replace `2` with `0` and see if that helps.

Comment: @dejanh its same again I don't see the parent menu item.